# How to fix file paths with 'file:///' in React SSR with Parcel 2?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, parceljs

I'm moving from Parcel 1 to Parcel 2 with my react SSR project and I have this problem: asset paths (like SVG or fonts) are being imported by this kind of code on server side:
`$3315a98ea5592134$exports = new URL("form-return.f796c309.svg", "file:" + __filename).toString();`
This is OK if it was just a node app, but this is react-SSR and I need it to be a URL, just like in Parcel 1. Otherwise in the browser it tries to reference file-url too.

Here are my configs:
package.json

```
"targets": {
        "ssr": {
            "source": "server/index.js",
            "distDir": "dist/server",
            "publicUrl": "dist/server",
            "context": "node",
            "includeNodeModules": false,
            "sourceMap": {
                "inline": false
            },
            "optimize": false
        },
        "client": {
            "outputFormat": "esmodule",
            "optimize": true,
            "source": "app/index.html",
            "distDir": "dist/client",
            "publicUrl": "dist/client",
            "context": "browser",
            "includeNodeModules": true,
            "sourceMap": false
        }
    },
```

.parcelrc

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "*.ico": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"],
    "*.{woff,woff2}": ["@parcel/transformer-raw"]
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./root",
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
        // "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "exclude": ["./node_modules/**/*"]
}
```

I tried different values of "context" and "outputFormat" options, also tweaking tsconfig.json, but to no result.

Also tried this tsconfig variant:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node"
```